# Ruby single line ternary in function, is returning boolean

Tags: ruby, ternary-operator

```
def fib(n)
  [0,1].include? n ? n : (fib(n-1) + fib(n-2))
end

fib 5 => false
```

Why is this? Since it works when broken out into standard if then else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Operator precedence. You're effectively doing this:

```
[0, 1].include? (n ? n : fib...)
```

That is, the result of `n ? n : (fib(n-1) + fib(n-2))` is found, and **that** is passed to `include?`.

Use parenthesis to force the order of evaluation you intend:

```
[0, 1].include?(n) ? n : (f(n - 1) + fib(n - 2))
```